# Jupyter kernel not starting (M1 Mac)

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

Jupyter notebook was working fine until recently. Running jupyter notebook in the terminal works, but if I try to open up a notebook the kernel fails to start, and the following error appears on loop:

```
[I 15:42:03.029 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .comm.comm import BaseComm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .comm import Comm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/comm/comm.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 35, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _psposix
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psposix.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

Any advice for how to fix this error? I have an M1 Mac (which has been giving me nightmares with trying to use python). The only thing I did in between it working and not working was installing sympy, but I uninstalled sympy and it still is not working. I have also tried reinstalling jupyterlab, but when I try to reinstall with conda it says the packages are missing. This is the output of the command where jupyter:

```
/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I also recommend adding the anaconda tag since it seems that it could be an issue with your anaconda installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by running this command as recommended by this medium page

```
jupyter kernelspec remove python3
```

https://medium.com/@mohamadhasan.sarvandani/how-to-solve-kernels-error-on-jupyter-notebook-e8e090ab747a